# Google's Function Plotter

Tags: graph, google-search

If you make a search at google.com for a mathematical equation google will in most cases automatically plot it for you.

For example, you can type in `sin(x)/x` or even a comma separated list such as `sin(x)/x, cos(x), x` to plot multiple functions on the same graph.

I know there's other Javascript plotting libraries, and I know that google offers other apis for charting, maps, etc.  So does google offer an api or way to embed this math plotter into other sites/applications?  I wasn't able to find any specific information about the plotter.

Comment: An answer to this question could be [function-plot](https://github.com/mauriciopoppe/function-plot).

Comment: @Skyost , you are almost saying google is using function-plot which is not the case ( yet great library )