# Replacing an equation and embedding a math function plotter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am actually searching for a javascript / jquery library where I can pass a function equation, such as sin(x^2), and it plots the graph. Example link:

```
http://www.greatgraphing.me/?plot=sin(x^2)
```

Furthermore, I would like to scan my website for function equations and replace them with this function graph embed. It should have navigation features (scrolling, dragging the stage etc).

Over the last 4 hours I have searched the net without satisfactory result. Even the popular [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/), [fooplot.com](http://fooplot.com/) and [jsxgraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) do not offer this kind of features. The only thing that comes close to what I need is [www.graph.tk](http://graph.tk/). You can pass 1 equation by URL but it has no embed feature (widget or alike).

Wolframalpha offers a [widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/gallery/view.jsp?id=97f58cc60361f36cb40942c5c9a9e029) but it seems to be just an embed without the option to pass the equation.

Update: Found out that [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/api/v0.3/docs/) offers an embed feature, if you purchase one of their API keys. Price is not stated.

I also considered using Google's geometry calculator but there seems to be [no embed features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281509/googles-function-plotter).

Before starting to build such a "graph embed" myself, I would like to ask if such a project exists already. Maybe it is hidden in some github repo and I just can't find it.

Thank you.

PS: If the question is too offtopic (saw the first close flag), even though it is related to js/jquery, where should I ask it? On Superuser? Please advice me. I am sure this is an important question for many math developers.

Comment: Hi! The question might close because it is "asking to recommend  [...] software library", which is off topic. I think the question is useful, but you should change it a little, or ask several more focused questions: "How to draw a graph on a canvas?", and later, when this is working: "I have a graph using [some-library] - how can I scroll and zoom?"

Comment: well its an easy thing to grab the url parameter and pass it to some function

Comment: @Kobi: Sounds like I have to develop it myself. I have setup mathjs and easeljs and built a tiny tool that plots on a canvas. However, as you guessed, it is missing the moving around plus an automatic zoom if the graph is plotted outside of the canvas. Here is the [early prototype](http://www.echteinfach.tv/formeln/analysis/allplot/?plot=sin%28x^2%29). And I need to write the jquery function to embed the plotter on arbitrary sites. Probably I use [function]sin(x^2)[/function] to identify equations on my site.

Comment: @johnSmith It is not easy if you use an external webservice which does not accept the equation in the URL. Plus the question is also about embedding.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV you can get the query parameter plot very simple and assign it to a variable, you can pass this to your webservice call, shouldnt be a problem, what problem are you facing ?

Comment: @johnSmith With my own webservice it would be simple of course. But I meant the other external services like desmos and fooplot that are not mine.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV they both do not seem to have a webservice ... check out this for example you can pass the equation as url parameter http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2

Comment: If I used wolframalpha, the next step would be to get the image placed into my website. It seems I need to code it myself.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I took the time to write a first prototype based on jquery, math.js and easeljs (about 300 KB with v0.0.1):

**graphobed**

Demo: http://www.matheretter.de/tools/graphobed.html

Source: http://www.matheretter.de/tools/graphobed.html 
or here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/echteinfachtv/graphobed/master/graphobed.js

Github repo: https://github.com/echteinfachtv/graphobed

Disclaimer: The code is a bit messy but worked in my tests. You just have to embed the js file, the script runs over all elements on your site and parses only if an enclosed equation has been found, the characters for enclosing are: `*# x^2*sin(x) #*`

[image: graphobed graph embedding]

I also added the possibility to change the graph later on by simply providing an input field. So after the embed you can change the graph as you wish:

[image: graphobed interactive]

Enjoy and improve the source code if you like :)

Comment: I found a lightweight alternative called Fooplot: https://github.com/dheera/fooplot - only 55 KB, can move the stage and zoom, but seems to rely on SVG instead of canvas.

Comment: I finally used fooplot by extending it with some features, here you find several live examples: http://www.mathelounge.de/223378/tutorial-funktionen-als-graphen-einbetten